# how to load data into postgresql from a data stream via jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql

how to load data into postgresql from a data stream  via jdbc
we will get a data stream or a Array in memory,
Is there any method to load the stream data into postgresql?
use insert is too much inefficient。

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a prepared statement with a batch insert.  Have a look at the page: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/, which describes both the performance and security benefits of this approach.  The code below came from that page.

```
String sql = "insert into employee (name, city, phone) values (?, ?, ?)";
Connection connection = new getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

final int batchSize = 1000;
int count = 0;

for (Employee employee: employees) {

    ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
    ps.setString(2, employee.getCity());
    ps.setString(3, employee.getPhone());
    ps.addBatch();

    if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
        ps.executeBatch();
    }
}
ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
ps.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,but I want to know if there's some way I can use  the method like                                                             Statement stmt=conn.createStatement()  stmt.setLocalInfileInputStream(InputStream input) in Mysql jdbc

Comment: `Statement stmt=conn.createStatement()  stmt.setLocalInfileInputStream(InputStream input) `