# Psql script not committing when executed from Java

Tags: java, cmd, psql, sqltransaction

I have a .bat file that executes the psql command to import a SQL script file. When I execute the .bat file from Windows command line, it executes correctly. But when I call the .bat file from Java (with ProcessBuilder), the script doesn't end. I'm not getting any errors, not in the InputStream, the ErrorStream not even in the DB (Postgresql) log.

```
ArrayList<String> cmdArgs2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmdArgs2.add("sql2dbs.bat");


        ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArgs2);
        logger.info(pb2.command().toString());

        Map<String, String> env = pb2.environment();
        env.put("PGPASSWORD", "user");

        Process p2 = pb2.start();

        BufferedReader stdError2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getErrorStream()));
        String s;
        while ((s = stdError2.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.info(s);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.info(s);
        }

        p2.waitFor();
```

The SQL script is very long that's why I'm not adding it. The script does have a COMMIT statement at the bottom.

Any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run batch scripts using `psql` to import data into a database. `psql` is made for interactive use, not to be (ab)used as an API. You can do this directly in Java via JDBC, see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960503/1630171) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11200576/1630171). Using JDBC will also give you far better control and debugging options compared to shelling out.